# What temporal patterns exist for neo4j or graph databases?

Tags: graph, design-patterns, neo4j

I'm looking for patterns (ideally with advantages/disadvantages) that can be used for databases concerning time.

One I can think of is to have a node representing a point in time or time period.

What others are there? What others have you used?

Comment: Perhaps this is interesting http://blog.neo4j.org/2012/02/modeling-multilevel-index-in-neoj4.html other approaches use timeline indexes in the lucene index-provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Not a good question for SO

This question is very open-ended, and SO is meant for questions with specific technical answers.

***TL;DR: Graph patterns are infinite. Start from the problem, not the possibilities.***

## Graph patterns are case-specific, not data-type specific

There isn't a set of temporal graph patterns, and even if there was, each pattern would be unique for a specific use-case, and close to useless elsewhere. What you should be asking yourself:

1. What will my queries need to look like?
2. What kind of information am I representing?
3. What information is relevant?
4. Should it be more granular, or more general?
5. Time, Date, or Datetime? Microtime? BC?

#### Context *really* matters.

Modelling information flow in a datacenter's network? Probably only need seconds and microseconds in a property on the relevant data.

Modelling evolution on the tree of life? Probably don't need *anything* from Time or even Date, instead using a float and an int for exponential notation, or a single int representing thousands of years.

## What is time?

#### Or at least, what is it to your data?

The three most common patterns I've seen (because they're the most flexible and easiest to work with in queries):

- Just stick dates or datetimes wherever they're relevant.
- `(cause)-->(event {datetime})`
- `(event)-->(datetime)` and `(datetime)-[:NEXT]->(datetime)-[:NEXT]->(datetime)`

However, even with these patterns there are still many open-ended questions. Consider a case of tracking modifications to files...

- Simply put create and modified dates on the File nodes?
- Put dates on a relationship between the user and the file?

  - Just a datetime, or read/write and duration?
- Event itself as a node with start, end, and duration, with relationships to the user and the file, and the change-set applied to the file?

  - Should that event have a relationships between it's chronological neighbors, or should that relationship be kept between the change-sets alone?

Comment: If you're really trying to find something that will work well for almost any problem, follow the pattern in human minds: only record a `:Moment` when something important happens, put the datetime on that `:Moment`. Group related `:Moment` into an `:Event` for that group. Other nodes only connect to the `:Event`, unless they were part of the important thing in the `:Moment`. Moments are chained in sequence, and can be handled regardless of real time.